# Use arbitrary fonts with Google apps

Tags: google-slides, font

Is it possible to use an arbitrary font with Google Slides or other Google apps? I'm running macOS and would like to be able to use fonts I have installed for Chinese and Native American languages – the fonts are in Open Type (.otf) and True Type (.ttc) format.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: For Docs you can try the [Extensis Fonts](https://gsuite.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/extensis_fonts/568288816452)